# Simpler regular expression for oracle regexp_replace

Tags: regex, oracle

I have a **|** separated string with 20 **|s** like `123|1|42|13||94123|2983191|2|98863|...|211|` upto 20 |. This is a oracle db column. The string is just 20 numbers followed by |.

I am trying to get a string out from it where I remove the numbers at position 4,6,8,9,11,12 and 13. Also, need to move the number at position 16 to position 4. Till now, I have got a regex like

`select regexp_replace(col1, '^((\d*\|){4})(\d*\|)(\d*\|)(\d*\|)(\d*\|)((\d*\|){2})(\d*\|)((\d*\|){3})((\d*\|){2})(\d*\|)(.*)$', '\1|\4|\6||\9||||||||') as cc from table`

This is where I get stuck since oracle only supports backreference upto 9 groups. Is there any way to make this regex simpler so it has lesser groups and can be fit into the replace? Any alternative solutions/suggestions are also welcome.

Note - The position counter begins at 0, so 123 in above string is the 0th number.

Edit: Example -

**Source string**

> |||14444|10107|227931|10115||10118||11361|11485||10110||11512|16666|||

**Expected result**

> |||16666|10107||10115||||||11512||||

Comment: Is there any other column in that table that uniquely identifies every row?

Comment: @Littlefoot - yes, there is a id column on this

Comment: Your expected result doesn't seem to agree with the first position being 0, because in that case 10107 is actually the number at position 4 that should be replaced with 16666.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the result you want by removing capture groups for the numbers you are removing from the string anyway, and writing (for example) `((\d*\|){2})` as `(\d*\|\d*\|)`. This reduces the number of capture groups to 7, allowing your code to work as is:

```
select regexp_replace(col1, 
     '^(\d*\|\d*\|\d*\|\d*\|)\d*\|(\d*\|)\d*\|(\d*\|)\d*\|\d*\|(\d*\|)\d*\|\d*\|\d*\|(\d*\|\d*\|)(\d*\|)(.*)$', 
     '\1\6\2|\3||\4|||\5|\7') as cc 
from table
```

Output (for your test data and also @Littlefoot good column example):

```
CC
|||14444|16666|227931|||||11361|||||11512|||||
0|1|2|3|16|5||7|||10||||14|15||17|18|19|
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3f8c1ff19f9a54856c5c397160db67af)

Comment: This is exactly what I was after. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As there's unique column (`ID`, as you said), see if this helps:

- split every column into rows
- compose them back (using `listagg`) which uses 2 `CASE`s:

  - one to remove values you don't want
  - another to properly sort them ("put value at position 16 to position 4")

Note that my result differs from yours; if I counted it correctly, 16666 isn't at position 16 but 17 so - 11512 has to be moved to position 4.

I also added another *dummy* row which is here to confirm whether I counted positions correctly, and to show why you have to use lines #10-12 (because of duplicates).

OK, here you are:

```
SQL> with test (id, col) as
  2    (
  3    select 1, '|||14444|10107|227931|10115||10118||11361|11485||10110||11512|16666|||' from dual union all
  4    select 2, '1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20'                     from dual
  5    ),
  6  temp as
  7    (select replace(regexp_substr(col, '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, column_value), '|', '') val,
  8            column_value lvl,
  9            id
 10     from test cross join table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 11                                              connect by level <= regexp_count(col, '\|') + 1
 12                                             ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 13    )
 14  select id,
 15    listagg(case when lvl in (4, 6, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13) then '|'
 16                 else val || case when lvl = 20 then '' else '|' end
 17            end, '')
 18            within group (order by case when lvl = 16 then 4
 19                                        when lvl =  4 then 16
 20                                        else lvl
 21                                   end) result
 22  from temp
 23  group by id;

        ID RESULT
---------- ------------------------------------------------------------
         1 |||11512|10107||10115|||||||10110|||16666|||
         2 1|2|3|16|5||7|||10||||14|15||17|18|19|20

SQL>
```

Comment: This isn't actually correct. There's an extra `|` between the values for columns 4 and 5, and no `|` for the missing column 16 value.

Comment: So true, @Nick; thank you. Fixed, with a little bit more typing & `case` involvement.

Comment: Appreciate the effort. Nick's answer is closer to what I am doing though and would be much faster in my case, so going with it. Cheers

Comment: No problem at all. Good luck!